# Quickfix/j automatically appending EventType as PUT

Tags: java, append, message, quickfix, quickfixj

Quickfix/J automatically appending **EventType** (865) as PUT - 1 whenever we are sending **NoEvents** (864) with group of **EventType** and **EventText** (868) with the order.

Here we are using quickfix 4.4

```
// Creating order
NewOrderSingle order = new NewOrderSingle(new ClOrdID("12343"), new Side(Side.BUY), new TransactTime(), new OrdType(OrdType.MARKET));
// Creating group
Group group = new Group(EventType.FIELD, EventText.FIELD);
// Setting field EventType as 3 - TENDER
group.setField(new EventType(3));
// Setting event Text as DEFAULT
group.setField(new EventText("DEFAULT"));
// Adding group to order
order.addGroup(group);
// Adding NoEvents as 1 since we added 1 group
order.set(new NoEvents(1));
```

The result for this is like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDlnk.png)
Here we see two fields of 865 - as 1 - PUT and 3 - TENDER

We added just one field on the order and expect only that field here.
Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution -
Group constructor arguments were incorrect

```
// 1st argument should be the field which represents the count of fields in group
// 2nd argument should be the type of first field
Group group = new Group(NoEvents.FIELD, EventType.FIELD);
```